# Fix windows 10 drive

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, uefi, bootloader

Basically I have an image of my windows 10 installations c drive, plus images of all the other microsoft restricted partitions etc, I would like to know where to put them on a fresh disk to get it to boot my windows 10. The different parts to boot were crossed between two disks due to the way I installed the OSes if you keep reading, that prevented me from simply cloning one whole disk. n.b. I'm using a uefi bios and had everything set up for that, not mbr

*CONTEXT:

The way I've had windows installed has been funny on my computer. As I initally decided to install linux mint on an ssd, using a hdd as data storage, and then later decided to install windows 10. I decided to install windows 10 on the hdd to avoid changing the way grub was set up (I unfortunately didn't remove the ssd during the process), that didn't work however and after the install was complete grub wouldn't let me boot linux.*

*Over the past few days I decided to create an image of the linux partition and try and fix it later, and then transfer windows over to the ssd. I had to create individual images of each of the partitions on the ssd as linux was on an lvm2 partition. After I created an image of my c drive partition I first tried to create partitions for the windows bootloader to transfer the iamges to them. After setting up all the partitions I wasn't able to boot windows up. What I would like to know is how to set up with all the correct partitions to get windows working. I still have all the data on my hdd, including the c drive and an image of it stored in my data partition along with all the other images.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more searching and I managed to find a fairly simple solution.
For anyone with the same problem, it's quite simple.

This article outlines all the steps in detail, I'll provide a quick summary
http://woshub.com/how-to-repair-deleted-efi-partition-in-windows-7/

First I wiped the ssd on a linux live flash drive, and then using gparted set the disk up for gpt, left 300Mb of space before an ntfs partition. Afterwards I used gnome-disks to transfer the image of my c drive to the ntfs partition. That's linux out of the way.

Next I booted from my win10 install flash drive and pressed shift+f10 to get cmd up. I used diskpart to create a 100mb efi partition and formatted it to fat32, then a 16mb microsoft system reserved partition (msr)

once all the partitions were set up I set the esi letter to G and began following the detailed instructions to copy files over and set up a few parameters that are too detailed to cover here (they're all covered in detail if you follow the link)

Hopefully this saves someone else some headaches later on :)